# iOS In App subscription - "A marketing opt-in incentive cannot be offered with this app"

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

One of our applications offers IAP, some consumable and some auto-renewable subscription.

When trying to add an (or to modify an existing) auto-renewable subscription, iTunes Connect displays this label in the "Add duration and pricing window" :

> ***A marketing opt-in incentive cannot be offered with this app.***

Does someone know how to enable opt-in at application or appId level?

Thanx

Comment: What does that actually mean? Is it talking about a free trial?

Comment: *As an incentive, you can offer users a free subscription extension when they opt in to share their contact information with you for marketing purposes. If you select Yes, a drop -down menu will be displayed that will allow you to select the incentive duration. The user’s opted-in information will be made available in the Sales and Trends module of iTunes Connect.*

For more information, see : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/13_ManagingIn-AppPurchases_Robert/ManagingIn-AppPurchases.html

Answer (score 3):

I belive that this relates to Newsstand and subscription magazines. Big publishers somehow managed to convince Apple to hand over details about subscribers to them, but this is to be "opt-in."

Since you're not (I assume) a big publisher you don't get this perk, so you can't offer it.

Comment: Sorry to contradict, but this feature is available for all applications offering IAP, no only for magazines. And thanx for your answer!

Comment: I think the documentation link you provide above gives the answer: it has to be a subscription (not _any_ IAP) and not free. When it first launched I remember it being only for big publishers... but maybe my memory is faulty or maybe the relaxed the requirement...

Comment: I'm sorry Stephen, but in my question I did specify we are creating subscription.

Comment: My app says "A marketing opt-in incentive cannot be offered with this app." when I create an Auto-Renew subscription. How do I toggle this? I don't want it, nor do I want the personal info prompt when a user tries to make a purchase.

Comment: The documentation (still) says that the opt-in scheme is still just available for magazines/Newsstand apps.  **"If the product is a Magazines & Newspapers app with Newsstand kit implemented, and an opt-in incentive is configured, the personal data sharing dialog appears, asking users to choose to share their information with you."** https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/CreatingInAppPurchaseProducts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013727-CH3-SW12